# Showing Custom Stencil Library in Visio

Tags: visio

Visio 2013 wont show custom Stencils in the "More Shapes" window unless the document units are Inches (imperial) despite specifically creating and saving a Metric stencil.

Can anyone reproduce ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known change, it depends on your system locale and office locale.

To show your metric stencil, add suffix "_M" to the name of the stencil, i.e. name it like "MyShapes_M.vssx"